# Excel file won't save

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

After opening and altering an Excel File,
I try to save it, using:

> excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();

But the data doesn't seems to save.

```
 private void ExportResultsToExcel()
 {
     string fullFilename = Regex.Match(Path, @".*\\([^\\]+$)").Groups[1].Value;
     string fileName = fullFilename.Substring(0, fullFilename.Length - 5);
     var templatePath = Path.Replace(fileName, "SolutionTemplate");
     var solutionPath = Path.Replace(fileName, fileName+"_Solution");
     System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, solutionPath);

     var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
     var workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
     var workbook = workbooks.Open(solutionPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                                            XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
                                            false, 0, true, 1, 0);
     var workSheets = workbook.Worksheets;
     var workSheet = (Worksheet) workSheets.Item[1];
     var rowIndex = 2;
     excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
     excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
     excelApp.Visible = false;
     excelApp.UserControl = false;
     excelApp.Interactive = false;
     foreach (var product in DemandData.Keys)
     {
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1] = product;
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 2] = Result[product][0];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 3] = Result[product][1];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 4] = Result[product][2];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 5] = Result[product][3];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 6] = Result[product][4];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 7] = Result[product][5];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 8] = Result[product][6];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 9] = Result[product][7];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 10] = Result[product][8];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 11] = Result[product][9];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 12] = Result[product][10];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 13] = Result[product][11];
         workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 14] = Result[product][12];
         rowIndex++;
     }
     int hWnd = excelApp.Application.Hwnd;
     //workbook.Save();
     excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheets);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
     workbook.Close();
     excelApp.Quit();
     TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(hWnd);

 }
```

Comment: Paste you full code and write your error message If you have it. Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: No errors messages- the changes just doesn't save.

Comment: Maybe there's an error in your foreach-loop?
Check if DemandData.Keys is not NULL and > 0.

Comment: Try wrapping your for loop around a Try Catch{} also prior to calling workbooks.Close(); move that code above the Marshall.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

Comment: No errors. In my opinion, it's an "excel issue".

Comment: check the whether function returning true or false...

Comment: Tried catching exceptions, but there are no exception.

Comment: KayzeSoze have you tried stepping thru and adding a watch to make sure that you are not getting any Null values..? opinions are one thing facts are another.. just give it a try.. and this is basic Interop code I never have issues saving an Excel file so perhaps you have some issue in the for loop let us know what you find

Comment: Where are you catching the exception..? I don't see where you are catching it..?

Comment: in this case, Save() method, doesn't return any value.

Comment: why do you use int hWnd = excelApp.Application.Hwnd; this is not really necessary..

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook); should be called after the close not the reverse for starters..

Comment: Guys,
1. I've added try-catch (localy, so you won't see it), and didn't get any exception.
2. When debugging, I can see the the worksheet is being altered.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change your work sheets line that you declare as well to this 
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

Comment: DJ KRAZE,
Could you please explain?
What do you mean by "Change your work sheets line that you declare as well to this"?

Comment: Also try to use the excelApp.SaveAs() method instead of save .. what is the name of your file.. I will post an example in the answer section.. I do this on a regular basis.. ok..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21574/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-kayzersoze)

Comment: In the future, please indent your code by four spaces or select it and press Control-K. You used the "Quote" command and not the "Code" command.

Comment: Code works fine now I will send you the solution in a .zip file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I see your issue.. in your open() method, you are opening it up as ReadOnly
you could try the following change this

```
var workbook = workbooks.Open(solutionPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                                            XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
                                            false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

to

```
var workbook = workbooks.Open(solutionPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", true,
                                            XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
                                            false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

Pass in **false** for the **ReadOnly** parameter of the Workbooks.Open method so that you can save it later using Workbook.Save method.

the other suggestions would be to also move the close to this location

```
 workbook.Close();
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheets);
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet);
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
```

look at Marshal.ReleaseComObject in MSDN and you could also set the objects = to null as well just to be safe after calling the 4 Marshal.ReleaseComObject() methods

Microsoft Reference [MarshalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx)